# EC2:Connection reset by peer

Tags: amazon-ec2

Hi i am configuring ftp on amazon ec2 mincro linux instance i have suceessfully install and configure vsftpd on my instance, and also i create user for my ftp. but when i ftp my instance it will give following error

Error:
"Connection reset by by peer"

can any one help me regarding this what was im going wrong, or what im missing,

Note i have configure instance firewall as following

Custom tcp rule:
Port range : 20  - 21
source : 0.0.00/0

any hep is greatly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using an instance for VPN and FTP([vsftpd](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/)) servers. Add this in the `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf`

```
pasv_addr_resolve=NO|YES
pasv_address=You Elastic IP Address|Hostname
pasv_min_port=2020
pasv_max_port=2020
```

Where `pasv_address` is your [Elastic IP Address](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#features) (set `pasv_addr_resolve=NO`) or you can use [dyndns](http://www.dyndns.com/) service and set `pasv_addr_resolve=YES` correspondingly. Then open 2020 and 21 ports in firewall. In this configuration you can use FTP server even in passive mode (Incoming connections are prohibited in you local PC).

[image]

All vsftpd config options are described [here](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html)

Comment: I had a similar [problem](http://superuser.com/questions/273378/keepass-synchronize-with-url-via-ftp-problem)

Comment: i do these setting but still this issue is not resolve and now it give this error :( Permission denied (publickey).
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer kindly help me in this regards what wrong im doing or missing some thing thanks in advance.